# Looking for dataset for testing address validation for Google maps API

Tags: data-request, postal-code, address

So I implemented an address validation using Google maps API and looking for some dataset of valid addresses for testing. I already used [Openaddreses](https://www.kaggle.com/openaddresses/openaddresses-europe) data which is great and covers lots of countries, but for some countries ( Like Slovakia, Romania, Portugal, Estonia ) only 3 percent of data had valid addresses.

I was wondering if anyone here had implemented an address validation before and let me know what kind of data source do you used for testing, I prefer if it's free service but if it's even a paid service, I appreciate it if you can let me know.

Comment: I'd suggest openstreetmap.org, but I think Openaddresses already uses that data

Comment: Yeah, the data is the same.